# Lucene search doesn't return results on Orientdb server restart

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I am using OrientDB 2.0.9 with a Java application. I am using graph Java API to create graph instance. I am facing an issue with Lucene index search.

I have entered some data in a vertex and then if I do a Lucene search, I get the result. Then I restarted orientdb server and then same Lucene search doesn't return any data inserted in last server run. Whereas if I do a normal field search without Lucene index, I can see all result.

```java
final OrientGraphFactory gFactory = new OrientGraphFactory("db_path").setupPool(0, 10);
OrientGraph graphDB = gFactory.getTx();
graphDB.setUseLightweightEdges(true);
OrientDynaElementIterable result = (OrientDynaElementIterable) graphDB.command(
        new OCommandSQL("select from KnowledgeElement where description LUCENE ?")
    ).execute(searchText);
```

I have also tried this with 2.1.4 server.

**Some more information which could help:** I have created vertex and lucene index by running below commands through console:

CREATE class KnowledgeElement extends V

CREATE property KnowledgeElement.description String

ALTER property KnowledgeElement.description collate ci

CREATE index KnowledgeElement.description on KnowledgeElement (description collate ci) FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am unable to get it work and therefore I am forced to replace lucene search by simple like search.

*I am still clueless about the problem. Any help is highly appreciated.*

Comment: Can you post your code with the query ?

Comment: Can you try with the latest 2.0.16 

http://orientdb.com/download-previous/

Comment: The code is as below:

Comment: final OrientGraphFactory gFactory = new OrientGraphFactory("db_path").setupPool(0, 10);                 OrientGraph graphDB = gFactory.getTx();  graphDB.setUseLightweightEdges(true);              OrientDynaElementIterable result = (OrientDynaElementIterable) graphDB.command(new OCommandSQL("select from KnowledgeElement where description LUCENE ?")).execute(searchText);                                                                         I have even tried this with 2.1.4 server.

Comment: Apologies for the unformatted code.

Comment: I have tried with 2.1.2 and it hasn't problems

Comment: @Ashish - I've edited your code into the question.  If you need to add code or other information to make your question more clear and answerable, It's generally preferred to go ahead and edit your question instead of leaving it in a comment (in part, because of the lack of formatting tools available in comments, as you noticed).  And, by the way, welcome to StackOverflow!